# Point and label visible despite all layers are turned off in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a QGIS workspace which has a graphics point and a label associated which I cannot delete or turn off. ALL the layers in the project workspace are turned off and yet still the graphic persists. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe the points and labels are annotations. Look at the annotation toolbar and select the labels or points. If they got selected, then they are annotations.

Comment: It is always helpful to add a screenshot to such questions.

Comment: Awesome, Ahmad. That is exactly what they were. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Erik!